# Toggle sub-form visibility to true while in-putting new record of same ID number

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form to track students' submitted paperwork. As someone enters the student's ID into the form, I have a query that populates a subform using the StudentID to show us if the student has previously submitted something.

It works great if there is already a matching StudentID. But, if there is not a matching StudentID I get

> Run-time error '2427': You entered an expression that has no value.

This is in the `AfterUpdate` StudentID event:

```
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "IntakePrevious_Q"
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "IntakePrevious_Q", acSaveYes
    [Intake_QSF].Requery

    If Me.StudentID = ([Intake_QSF]![StudentID]) Then
        Me.Intake_QSF.Visible = True        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure which row causes your error (you could find out this when debugging), but I guess it is the `If` row. Please check `If Me.StudentID = (Nz([Intake_QSF]![StudentID],"")) Then
` to avoid comparing your `StudentID` with a null value.

Comment: Yes, it is the "If" row. I tried the code you posted and get another runtime error--only when it is a new StudentID record--if there is an existing record it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as you already mentioned, that there is no recordset.

Replace

```
If Me.StudentID = ([Intake_QSF]![StudentID]) Then
    Me.Intake_QSF.Visible = True        
End If
```

by this:

```
Me.Intake_QSF.Visible = Me.Intake_QSF.Form.Recordset.RecordCount > 0
```

It will check if there are records at all and set the boolean value of the `Visible` property.

Edit:

Alternatively you could check if the current record of the subform is a new record:

```
Me.Intake_QSF.Visible = Not Me.Intake_QSF.Form.NewRecord
```